# Job offer: bad wording?

Tags: job-description

I just changed my position and relocated to Japan. Everything is fine for now.

As we need someone else we are looking for an embedded engineer.
We had a couple of interesting resume and invited them to interviews.

When asked "How would you manage a UART protocol for [random project]*?"
all of them answered: I never used UART or -even worst- "UART?".

If it was only from one candidate I would have assume that his resume might be a bit off, but its 7 candidates & none of them are fresh graduates.

Is the embedded word on **the job-offer** poorly chosen?

*[project] refers to a hypothetical project used for the whole interview as a test case, candidates where given all requirements and system information required to give a global answer, before being guided deeper into the simulation.

Note: I never expected the interview question to yield those results.

To make it really clear, its not about the question in the interview but the use of the embedded word on the job offer

Comment: I can tell you that I've done firmware in the past, am generally considered a good programmer, and I had to look up the term.  And despite having done 5 years of embedded programming I never interfaced with the UART directly.  If you need this specific experience its a legit question, but I would not assume that every embedded engineer has programmed one.

Comment: @GabeSechan I'ld definitely understand not having programmed one, but having to look up the term is not something I can understand. Even if you only use libraries you should have method called "send_uart(bla)" or even send(uart0, bla);. I am pretty sure that uart/serial/rs232 should be common knowledge if you work in the embedded field.

Comment: never did serial communication.  I have done imaging, scanning, motor control, etc.  Just never was on the team that did communication, always had higher level abstractions.  I'd seen the term and I remembered it had something to do with a connector.  As for rs232-  everything I've ever done is USB.  I would expect rs232 to be dead by now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about technical interviews in embedded programming and not about navigating the workplace

Comment: UART communication will stay on embedded as long as pic will be used -i.e. probably forever-, on topic: then it is a wording trouble, we should have pointed out that we are looking for someone who could handle communication protocols.

Comment: Embedded/Legacy Communication protocol I would tell, I'am more a sysadmin than a dev, but when I think communication protocol, it's more wifi/routing/cisco iso/ipfw/etc.., and I still do serial modem communition, but never heard the term UART except in my comptia a+ exam.

Comment: @Ebya Its totally legitamate to need that experience and ask about it.  Just understand that a lot of very good embedded developers won't have it.  If its a hard requirement, ask about it in the phone screen so not to waste each other's time.

Comment: @yagmoth555  ; Definitely a wording problem then.

Comment: I guess the problem was that they were a "bit" off! :P

Comment: Question put on hold, we can't evaluate the appropriateness of specific interview questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 'layers' of embedded engineering / firmware development.
You're probably more likely to get hits in the area you seem to be interested in if you pick candidates with electronics/engineering qualifications than if you pick those with software/programming.
The former are more likely to have worked with micro-controllers (ARM Cortex, PIC, 8051 variants) where UART interfacing is often a daily task, while the latter are more likely to have worked on Linux/Android platforms which are both somewhat divorced from the actual hardware, as well as not using the old legacy serial ports anymore (if they even exist in that environment).

Answer (score 5):

> When asked "How would you manage an UART protocol for [random project]?" all of them answered: I never used UART or -even worst- "UART?".

If you're advertising for an electronics / firmware type position, and if none have heard of the term UART (or know what it means) then I suspect the job description may have been off. It's a widely used and understood term, and if you've attracted a half dozen people from your ad that *don't* know its meaning then I'd start by looking at the recruitment process up to the interview stage.

That being said, even ignoring the above, the question itself is still rather vague. The best answer you could really hope for are a few clarification questions back such as "What do you mean by manage? Manage as in how would I design it from the ground up, how would I implement the protocol in software when handed the specification, what constraints would I implement on the hardware side to make sure the protocol was within spec, etc."

Comment: Indeed the question was more deep. I setup a fake project with them with requirements. The whole interview was based on this project -will edit OP-. Seven had no idea, two other candidates answered flawlessly to the question.

Comment: @Ebya I didn't realise you had some that did have an idea. It still seems like a high number that didn't know, but you'll always get underqualified people that apply for roles - the key is trying to filter more of them out before the interview stage (though admittedly that's a hard thing to do accurately!)

Answer (score 4):

You mentioned you are in Japan, so if the candidates are Japanese, there is a good chance that they use another term for it in their native language. I live and work in Japan too, and while I speak Japanese at work, they tend to use actual Japanese words when talking about programming and not English words or acronyms. When I don't know the Japanese word for something and use the English version of it, the majority of them have no idea what I am talking about. It is entirely possibly they are just unfamiliar with that particular term, rather than being unfamiliar with the concept.

Comment: I'll double check this. Strangely I didn't think about that...

Comment: @Ebya Most tech terms in Japan are derived from English and just used in katakana. But maybe you could try explaining it within the context of シリアル通信... sometimes all the acronyms are confusing to Japanese. https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/UART